# How to protect expired session clean-up with a security constraint?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, session, google-cloud-datastore

**The protection attempt**

The URL

```
http://[GAE app URL]/_ah/sessioncleanup?clear
```

clears 100 expired sessions from the GAE datastore (so it seems).

I wanted to protect this URL so that it can be called from within the app using an entry in `cron.xml` like

```
<cronentries>
  [...]

  <cron>
    <url>/_ah/sessioncleanup?clear</url>
    <description>Clean 100 expired sessions up</description>
    <schedule>[Schedule]</schedule>
  </cron>
</cronentries>
```

but not from just any user following the URL of the form given above.

So I added the following code to `web.xml`:

```
<web-app>
[...]

  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>session-clean-up</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/_ah/sessioncleanup</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

I omitted adding the following to `web.xml` since the session clean-up takes place using a manual URL invocation without it:

```
<web-app>
  [...]

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>_ah_sessioncleanup</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.SessionCleanupServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>_ah_sessioncleanup</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/sessioncleanup</url;-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**Result**

Sadly, after deployment of this code into production, I find that no protection has been given by the addition of the `<security-constraint>` above to either

```
http://[GAE app URL]/_ah/sessioncleanup?clear
```

or

```
http://[GAE app URL]/_ah/sessioncleanup
```

**Background information**

I based my code above on the posting by a Googler as referenced in [GAE issue 10047 (Request to document or publish code for SessionCleanupServlet)](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10047&can=4&sort=priority&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log).

**My question**

Does anyone know how I can solve my problem?

Comment: Why limit the access? Worst case someone will hit this for you, cleaning up expired sessions :)

Comment: @maximbr It's not a serious issue, I agree. I just don't want to expose this functionality to anyone who is not an administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tweaking my entry in `web.xml` by appending `/*` to the URL pattern results in success. The relevant `web.xml` entry becomes:

```
    <web-app>
    [...]

      <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
          <web-resource-name>session-clean-up</web-resource-name>
          <url-pattern>/_ah/sessioncleanup/[asterisk]</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
          <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
      </security-constraint>
    </web-app>
```